# compare two fields in dictionnary python

Tags: python

```
    pattern_poteaux = r"(POT|PHT)+[-]+[0-9]{5}[-]+[a-zA-Z]{2}[-][0-9]*"
    pattern_chambre = r"CHB+[-]+[0-9]+[-]+[a-zA-Z]{2}[-]+[0-9]*"

"""
@param :
1: pattern regex
2: string
return Booleen si la référence est valide
"""
def attribute_check(pattern, sample_str):
    if re.search(pattern, sample_str) is not None:
        return True
    else:
        return False

"""
@param: chaine de caractère
return : incrémente la référence de 1 
"""
reference_incrementee = []
reference_invalide = []
def increment_ref(pattern, sample_str):
    if attribute_check(pattern, sample_str) == True:
        result = re.sub(r'[^-]+[0-9]$', lambda x: str(int(x.group()) + 1).zfill(len(x.group())), sample_str)
        reference_incrementee.append(sample_str)
    else:
        reference_invalide.append(sample_str)
```

I have now two dict :

## dico netdiesigner

```
dicorefCh = {u'CHB-19157-FT-5': [25310, (637904.4632999972, 6480201.605900001), u'LFA-BL05']}
```

## dico ax_chamber

```
dicorefCh2 ={1: [u'CHB-16175-FT-91', u'LFA-BL05'],2:[u'CHB-16175-FT-92', u'LFA-BL04']}
```

to compare "CODE_SITE" I did  the following code :

```
for values in DicorefCh2.values():
    for v in DicorefCh.values():
        if values[1] == v[2]:
        increment_ref(pattern_chambre, ref_ax_chambre)
```

is there a better way to do this ? knowing that I have a lot of records 50,000 or so.

thanks

Comment: You do nothing with `result = ...` in `increment_ref`: Is that intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, you want to call the function `increment_ref` whenever you find a match and the function does not take the value as input. So you could just count the matches and call the function afterwards as often as you found matches.
Python offers the `set` type to find the intersections you are looking for. However, you did not mention if the "CODE_SITE" is unique or can appear several times in each dictionary, so I assume the more general case and need to deal with the multiple appearances. Here, the standard library offers `collections.Counter`. To count the appearance. Then the number of matches is the sum of the product of the appearances of the CODE_SITE in each dict.
Putting these words into code gives the following:

```py
from collections import Counter

dicorefCh = {u'CHB-19157-FT-5': [25310, (637904.4632999972, 6480201.605900001), u'LFA-BL05']}
dicorefCh2 ={1: [u'CHB-16175-FT-91', u'LFA-BL05'],2:[u'CHB-16175-FT-92', u'LFA-BL04']}

# count appearence in first dict
code_sites_1 = [value[2] for value in dicorefCh.values()]
sites_counter_1 = Counter(code_sites_1)

# count appearance in second dict
code_sites_2 = [value[1] for value in dicorefCh2.values()]
sites_counter_2 = Counter(code_sites_2)

# find the intersections
intersections = set(sites_counter_1).intersection(sites_counter_2)

# sum the products
total = sum(
    sites_counter_1[site] * sites_counter_2[site] 
    for site in intersections
)

# call function total times
for i in range(total):
    increment_ref(pattern_chambre, ref_ax_chambre)
```

Comment: thanks for your post,  just one question please why did you use the sum of the counters ?

Comment: I used it to cover the case in which a "CODE_SITE" appears multiple times in one of the dictionaries. Imagine a site appears twice in dicorefCh2 and three times in dicorefCh, then your outer loop over dicorefCh2 will find three matches in the inner loop over dicorefCh two times. So two times three is the number of combinations.